# Design polymorphism without downcasting

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I have a class which works with a hardware device. This device supports a number of commands, and I want to implement a common *SendCommand* function. Commands might or might not have input parameters and/or output result.

What I can do is to write an abstract command type class, and a number of derived command type classes. Those derived classes would actually be different with those input/output specifics of commands.

Now I want `SendCommand` to return a `Task<SpecificCommandType>`, that is, task of derived class, but with current design I can only return `Task<BaseCommandType>`.

I will explain with simple skeleton code:

Classes:

```
public abstract class BaseCommandType { ... }

public class CommandType1 : BaseCommandType {
    TaskCompletionSource<CommandType1> Tcs;
}

public class CommandType2 : BaseCommandType {
    TaskCompletionSource<CommandType2> Tcs;
}
```

My function:

```
public Task<T> SendCommand<T>(BaseCommandType type) where T : BaseCommandType {
    ...
    // if I implement TaskCompletionSource<BaseCommandType> Tcs
    // in abstract class, then I can return type.Tcs.Task, and remove
    // generics.
    // But how can I return Task<T>? 
}
```

I was planned to use this func like this:

```
CommandTypeX cmd = new CommandTypeX(...);
SendCommand<CommandTypeX>(cmd).ContinueWith(t => {
    // access some specifics of t.Result as CommandTypeX
});
```

How should I design my classes to be able to return `Task<CommandTypeX>`?

Or is there a better way to do something I need (without downcast)?

**Update1**:
To be more precise, I can do it like this with downcast (can do I, isn't it?):

```
public abstract class BaseCommandType {
    public TaskCompletionSource<BaseCommandType> Tcs;
}

public class CommandTypeX : BaseCommandType { }

public Task<BaseCommandType> SendCommand(BaseCommandType type) {
    ...
    return type.Tcs.Task;
}

// when task finishes:
type.Tcs.SetResult(type); // where type is actually of CommandTypeX

// usage:
CommandTypeX cmd = new CommandTypeX(...);
SendCommand(cmd).ContinueWith(t => {
    CommandTypeX command = t.Result as CommandTypeX;
    if (command != null) ...
});
```

But that's exactly what I want to avoid in first place.

**Update2**:
I think I found another way of going, but still looks not well for me.

```
public abstract class BaseCommandType {
    internal abstract void SetTcs<T>(TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs);
    internal abstract void HandleData(byte[] data);
}

public class CommandType1 : BaseCommandType {
    private TaskCompletionSource<CommandType1> _tcs1 = new TaskCompletionSource<CommandType1>();
    public string Data1;

    internal override void SetTcs<T>(TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs)
    {
        _tcs1 = tcs as TaskCompletionSource<CommandType1>;
    }

    internal override void HandleData(byte[] data)
    {
        // Data1 = someFuncOn(data)
        _tcs1.TrySetResult(this);
    }
}

public class CommandType2 : BaseCommandType {
    private TaskCompletionSource<CommandType2> _tcs2 = new TaskCompletionSource<CommandType2>();
    public int[] Data2;

    internal override void SetTcs<T>(TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs)
    {
        _tcs2 = tcs as TaskCompletionSource<CommandType2>;
    }

    internal override void HandleData(byte[] data)
    {
        // Data2 = someFuncOn(data)
        _tcs2.TrySetResult(this);
    }
}

public class Device {
    private List<BaseCommandType> _commandList = new List<BaseCommandType>();

    public Task<T> SendCommand<T>(T t) where T : BaseCommandType
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        t.SetTcs<T>(tcs);
        _commandList.Add(t);

        // later in other thread then device answers
        // locate command in list
        // BaseCommandType c = _commandList[some index];
        // _commandList.RemoveAt(some index);
        // c.HandleData(null);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}

// usage like this:
CommandType2 command = new CommandType2();
device.SendCommand<CommandType2>(command).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            CommandType2 command2 = t.Result;
            // use command2.Data2 here;
        });
```

Is this way better than in update1? At least I can hide the casting logic inside the library so externally everything would be type safe and robust.
Or how can I further improve on this?

Comment: This looks like a covariance problem. Note you will need `BaseCommandType` to be or implement an interface for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understood it right, but...

```
public abstract class BaseCommandType<T>
{
    public abstract TaskCompletionSource<T> Tcs { get; }
}
public class CommandType1 : BaseCommandType<CommandType1>
{
}
public class CommandType2 : BaseCommandType<CommandType2>
{
}


public Task<T> SendCommand<T>(T type) where T : BaseCommandType<T>
{
    return type.Tcs.Task;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you cannot have generic input parameter, than instead of downcasting define abstract beahvior on BaseCommandType, which you would call in ContinueWith method, and override it in your commands. If you don't know the input type you cannot make it generic.

Comment: Unfortunately, I should stick with 'type' parameter as of base class or interface for internal purposes, and not as a generic. That's because I use those derived class instances in common list, and use overloaded methods to achive the goals of SendCommand.

Comment: Well, maybe I say it wrong.. I can make 'type' parameter as generic T, but I can't make type T generic itself. So, I think base abstract class shouldn't be generic. The only major requirement on 'type' is that I should be able to add it to List<BaseCommandType>. With BaseCommandType<T> base class I will fail to do so.

Comment: _"I should be able to add it to List<BaseCommandType>"_ -- with the constraint you showed, i.e. `where T: BaseCommandType`, you can. You already stated you _don't_ want `BaseCommandType` to be generic, so difficulties in making it so shouldn't be relevant here.

Comment: I simply was pointing that supplied answer with `BaseCommandType<T>` wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Things I don't understand about your question:

1. Why the restriction on the parameter type for `SendCommand<T>(BaseCommandType)`? What wouldn't work if you make that method `SendCommand<T>(T)` instead?
2. Why are you using `ContinueWith()`? `await` would be easier and more expressive.

Ignoring those for a moment, I would expect you should be able to do something like this:

```
public async Task<T> SendCommand<T>(BaseCommandType type) where T : BaseCommandType
{
    return await type.Tcs.Task as T;
}
```

Personally, I would go all-generic. But you say you can't for whatever reason, so you're going to have to cast at some point. Avoiding casting simply isn't possible with that constraint. The above seems like the easiest, most usable approach to do that.

If the above does not address your need, please improve the question by including a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly all the design restrictions and requirements, what you've tried, and explain why what you've tried does not meet your goal.

Comment: First, `SendCommand<T>(T type)` is ok unless T is generic itself. Second, I didn't use await because I'm targeting .Net 4.0. So, I can't check your code, but if I do `return type.Tcs.Task as Task<T>;` NullReferenceException is thrown so cast fails. Please see my comment on _Jan Muncinsky_ answer for `type` constraints.

Comment: _"unless T is generic itself"_ -- what's that got to do with anything? _"NullReferenceException is thrown"_ -- not sure what that means. There's no real code here, so I don't see how any exception could be thrown. Only in the context of a [mcve] could that happen. Beyond that, there's nothing in the expression `type.Tcs.Task as Task<T>` that would throw `NullReferenceException` unless you simply have not initialized the `Tcs` value in the first place.